# Standup bot for Telegram

Tags: project-management

I need telegram bot for weekly stand ups. Earlier I used Alice StandUp Bot for Slack, and I am pleased with it's functionality.

What I need now in Telegram:

- Set custom time of standup;
- Send notifications before standup for all team members;
- Post results after getting all responses into common team group.

I googled and didn't find anything I was searching for. Could you suggest something?